# Why is my RestController not working when I created a new class

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have my main class in which I have used RestController and it works fine

```
package dev.rizwan.movieapi;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class MoviesApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MoviesApplication.class, args);
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String apiRoot() {
        return "This is the root of API";
    }
}
```

when I go to localhost:8080 it shows "This is the root of API"

I have created another class

```
package dev.rizwan.movieapi;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/movies")
public class MovieController {

    @GetMapping
    public String getAllMovies () {
        return "All Movies";
    }
}
```

but when I go to localhost:8080/api/v1/movies it is showing whitelabel error page

please help....

I was expecting it to show "All Movies" When I go to localhost:8080/api/v1/movies

Answer (score -1):

Hope this worked it:

Just change this :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/movies")
public class MovieController {

    @GetMapping
    public String getAllMovies () {
        return "All Movies";
    }
}
```

with :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class MovieController {

    @GetMapping("/movies")
    public String getAllMovies () {
        return "All Movies";
    }
}
```